# div with max-width not taking the max width

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a page with  a div centered within a "main" div. The main div is full width and the inner div has a max-width equal to the width of the "main" div. When filling it up with elements it only fills up about half the screen. What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:
I noticed that some people misunderstood the text above. My elements (with float: left) will move beneath each other after 4 of them. At that point the div is about 1000px wide. This means that the max-width isn't 100% but somehow 50%. I checked in the browser and CSS but there is no other selector overriding those values.

CSS: (in sass)

```
#main
  z-index: 0
  width: 100%
  min-height: calc( 100% )
  background: #FFFFFF
  position: absolute
  left: 0px
  top: 0px
  padding: 50px 0px
  text-align: center
  div.container
    position: absolute
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    display: block
    max-height: 100%
    margin: 0 auto
    width: auto
    max-width: 100%
    overflow-y: auto
    overflow-x: hidden
    text-align: left

div.box
  width: 220px
  height: 200px
  border: 1px solid #5774FF
  padding: 19px
  margin: 10px
  float: left
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #CCC
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <form action="/save" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="code" name="name"/>
                <select name="education">
                    <option value="3">option 3</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're centering the `container` using the following code:

```
position: absolute
top: 50%
left: 50%
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

When you're giving an element a `position: absolute` and giving a `left: 50%`, it will automatically move itself and it's subsequent children (if the children doesn't have `position: absolute`) to `50%` from the left.

If you want the container to take up the full width, you'll have to remove the following:

```
position: absolute
top: 50%
left: 50%
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Comment: That makes sense. But what is the solution to center the div horizontally AND vertically if I can't use this?

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` will prevent elements from being wider than that specified, but will not make them wider.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your `css`. Hope it helps:

```css
#main {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  }
  div.container{
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    }

div.box{
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #5774FF;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #CCC;
    float: none;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <form action="/save" method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="code" name="name"/>
                <select name="education">
                    <option value="3">option 3</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically telling the browser that the container `div` can have a maximum width of 100% of its parent. That makes the container `div` fluid so it will respond to different screen sizes.

It only takes up about half of the screen because it stretches to the size required for its child elements.